# Change of direction in physics when an object in motion stops

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, speed

Consider an object moving with an acceleration $a = -1 \text{m/s}^2$ starting with speed  $v(0) = 4 \text{m/s}$ towards east and stopped after 4 seconds.
(There are no friction.)

After 4 seconds, the object would have speed $v(4\text{s})=0$.

- **Question 1:** Does the object get value of a null vector (0 vector) after it completely stops?
- **Question 2:** Since the object was moving toward east and then stopped at 4 seconds, can it be said that the object changed directions when it stopped?

I mean, the direction changes : East -> None **and** The vector changes to a null vector too.

- **Question 3:** The object stopped moving so it doesn't have a direction. So, is a change from east to none make a valid 'directional change'?

Sorry for the bad english..... it isn't my native language

Comment: The object is the object. A vector is a directional property of the object. Where the object's position and velocity vectors point and what length they have depends entirely on the observer's coordinate system. Two different observers can describe the object's movement with different position and velocity vectors and they would both be right.

Comment: @CuriousOne
Could you tell me a bit more?
The object stopped moving so it doesn't have a direction. So, is a change from east to none make a valid 'directional change'?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Whenever you find yourself making a list of questions, please stop and instead post each question separately. The goal of this site is to produce clear and correct sets of specific questions and answers. Putting multiple questions in one post prevents this. Now to talk about the specific question: it's not at all clear what you mean by "Is the object a null vector".

Comment: @DanielSank Sorry for my bad english...  
I mean that the object gets a value of null in vector (0vector)

Comment: Apologizing is not necessary, and unfortunately it doesn't help us understand the question. Can you please explain (by editing your post) what you mean by "Is the object a null vector"?

Comment: @DanielSank Edited.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. If an object is not moving then it's velocity vector is zero. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @DanielSank No.....

What I means is : If an object stops moving and gets the value of a null vector it doesn't have a direction value.
So, I'm asking whether the change of direction value from a vector to null vector means the physical change of direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you are asking more about language rather than about physics.

An important concept is *velocity*. Velocity is a vector that points in the direction of travel of the object and its magnitude is the speed of the object. In the following I assume you are talking about velocity whenever you talk about vectors in your question. 
In that case,

**Question 1.** The velocity will be (in, say, three dimensions) $\vec v=(0,0,0)$. That is probably what you mean by null vector.

**Question 2.** The issue here is that the velocity doesn't point in *any* direction (direction simply is not defined for a vector like (0,0,0)). You may or may not call the change {*going east* $\to$ *going nowhere*} a direction change, it is up to you. These are just words though, the important point is, that the motion is not directed when the speed of an object is zero.

**Question 3.** Again, I don't think there is a convention for this. Just say something like "it stopped moving, so direction is not defined."